# How to get health of an elasticsearch cluster using python API?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to get the health of an elasticsearch cluster similar to the command

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

but using python. I did the following

```
from elasticsearch.client import ClusterClient
esc = ClusterClient([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
esc.health();
```

but all I get is an

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transport'
```

I played around with some parameters for health() such us index and level but I mess around the syntax. Has someone a working example?

Regards,
Tobi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use the Cluster API directly, try this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
print(es.cluster.health())
```

Comment: Sorry, was my first post.

Comment: Found an entry in the documentation: __The instance has attributes cat, cluster, indices, nodes and snapshot that provide access to instances of CatClient, ClusterClient, IndicesClient, NodesClient and SnapshotClient respectively. This is the preferred (and only supported) way to get access to those classes and their methods.__

Answer (score 3):

```html
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
print(es.cat.health())
```